# Great scraping tools/ data mining tools for bulk of websites, extracting few emails from each?

Tags: python, data, scraping

I have been looking for good open source tools / softwares that can read certain patterns and scrape a bulk of provided websites...

My use case is like this:
I have a list of ~900 company websites that I can feed into a scraper.
Say, I want to scrape the head of the sales department's contact for each website.

Is there a good tools or software that is really well optimized for such task?
I looked to see if I can build one myself, but most were kind of tools that I have to write a specific script for each website, which doesn't really suit my usecase..